# Backbone Marionette ItemView's Events not triggering with specifiers 

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Have the following view :

```
ContactsApp.SettingsView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.bindTo(this.model, "change", this.modelChanged);
    },
    modelChanged: function (model, value) {
        console.log(this.model.get('search'));
        this.render();
    },
    events: {
        'click .clickable': 'GoTo',
        'keyup input[type=text]': 'search'
    },
    GoTo: function (ev) {
        var dest = $(ev.target).data('dest');
        if (dest == undefined) { return; }
        if (dest === "next") { this.model.nextPage(); return; }
        if (dest === "prev") { this.model.previousPage(); return; }
        this.model.set({ page: dest });
    },
    search :  function (ev) {
        console.log('search');
    },
    template: "#additional-stuff-template"
});
```

And My Template :

```
<script type="text/template" id="additional-stuff-template">

    <span class="clickable" data-dest="1">First</span>&nbsp;  
    <span class="clickable" data-dest="prev">Previous</span>&nbsp;
     <input type="text" value="{{ page }}"  size="3" /> of {{ pages}} 
      <span class="clickable" data-dest="next">Next</span>&nbsp;
    <span class="clickable" data-dest="{{ pages }}">Last</span> &nbsp;
      Search : <input type="text" class="search" value="{{ search }}"  size="15" /> 
</script>
```

The events dont fire.  if i change

```
events: {
    'click .clickable': 'GoTo',
    'keyup input[type=text]': 'search'
},
```

to

```
events: {
    'click': 'GoTo',
    'keyup': 'search'
},
```

I can get the click event to run but its not solely on the span's  (had the same issue with anchor tags as well.

I know this is something stupid i am doing ...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it wasnt something i was doing that was stupid.

It turns out that this can happen if you  have

jquery.validate   1.5.5
and
jquery 1.7.2
(there may be other versions that this effects this was just the one i had)

removing jquery.validate (which i wasnt using) made it start working again